# Install profile that automatically inserts data / config settings

Tags: 7, installation-profiles

I am trying to create a custom installation profile for small internal usage and I'd like to hide certain steps and also implement new functions as a quick-and-dirty way to pre-populate some default content (nodes, blocks, menus) and configuration settings (wysiwyg) by inserting them into the database during the profile installation.

I am using the standard profile as a guide to work from as well as following [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1022020), but having trouble getting this to work smoothly and since it's all pre-installation I can't use devel to troubleshoot (it's not enabled yet).

Let's call the custom installation profile `customprofile` and the files I have are:

- customprofile_profile.info
- customprofile_profile.profile
- customprofile_profile.install

I've figured out (for example) how to override the "Select locale" step and hard-code that to be English in `customprofile_profile.profile`:

```
function customprofile_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state) {
  $tasks['install_select_locale']['display'] = FALSE;
  $tasks['install_select_locale']['function'] = 'customprofile_select_locale';
}

function customprofile_select_locale (&$install_state) {
  $install_state['parameters']['locale'] = 'en';
}
```

...but I haven't been able to track down the syntax for:

1) inserting a new step at the end of the profile install

2) inserting some SQL (I found [this old post](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/5-step-drupal-distributions) but it seems to be for Drupal 6 and both the profile syntax and SQL insertion are incompatible with Drupal 7)

Any guidance for next steps on either/both of these would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might find drush-make useful, especially if you already have a codebase setup that you would like to replicate.  As outlined in [this blog post](http://www.webomelette.com/how-use-drush-make-your-daily-routine):

> Drush Make includes 2 commands which are already built in Drush
>   itself:
>
> - make — Turns a .makefile into a Drupal codebase.
> - make-generate — Generates a .makefile from the current Drupal site.
>
> Both commands are related to a .makefile — flat text file with Drush
>   Make instructions. You can read more about .makefile syntax [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/make.txt).

Comment: It looks like it would be useful to learn more about drush-make, but unless I'm missing something it doesn't seem to help with the default content/config portion, right?

Comment: Ah no, just codebase, you can create content/config defaults using the Features module I believe.